# Unparsable date format

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, dateparser

I am attempting to parse a date String but get this error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Oct 1, 1997, 12:00:00 AM"

This is the method I am using to parse the `Date`:

```
public static Date parse(@NonNull String dateString, @NonNull String dateFormat) {
    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    try {
        return sdf.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Where the `dateString` is `Oct 1, 1997, 12:00:00 AM` and the `dateFormat` is `MMM d, yyyy, HH:mm:ss a`.

Why is it failing to parse the date?

Comment: is this code running on a machine with a Locale other than EN??

Comment: should it be `MMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm:ss a` since days can be two digits?

Comment: No (to first question). `dd` seems to be for seems to just add `0` padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is throwing an exception because the string Date is not valid for the string pattern, look in the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

concretely, if the hour is in a format between 0-23 then the string is `HH`, but if you use a 1-12 AM, PM then you have to use `hh`

here is some ref code:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Date x = parse("Oct 1, 1997, 12:00:00 AM", "MMM d, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a");
        System.out.println("X String: " + x); 
    }
    
    public static Date parse(String dateString, String dateFormat) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        try {
            return sdf.parse(dateString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("E???");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and if you need to edit, here the ideone code:

https://ideone.com/ccwo2Y

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should use "h" instead of "H". Lowercase h refers to 0-12 capital one refers to 0-24.
Overall it should be
`MMM d, yyyy, hh:mm:ss a`

Answer (score 3):

If you change the SimpleDateFormat to DateTimeFormatter the exception shows the error:

```
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Conflict found: Field AmPmOfDay 1 differs from AmPmOfDay 0 derived from 12:00
```

For the 12:00 time it expects it to be PM. if you mean midnight instead, it should be 00:00 AM.